Question about uniqueness of Harmonic function on Unit Disk
Say I have a function $u(r,\theta)$ defined on the unit disk, which satisfies Laplace's equation on the interior of the disk, thus making $u$ harmonic. Let $f(\theta)$ be the boundary condition on the boundary of the disk, and let $$\lim_{r \to 1} u(r,\theta) = f(\theta)$$ uniformly. I know that this doesn't hold if this limit is pointwise, but if it's uniform, then we can say that $u$ is uniquely identical to $f$ on all $(r,\theta)$. My question is, why can we say this? It seems counter-intuitive. Further, if that is true, then what is $$\lim_{r \to 0} u(r,\theta)$$? This would be equal to $f(\theta)$ and not depend on $r$, but what happens if the limit of $r$ tends to $0$? This point would be "equal" to an infinite amount of lines at the same time.
Furthermore, if this is true, then the only functions that $u(r,\theta)$ could be equal to is $a\theta + b$, because the only way for $f(\theta)$ to be harmonic is for the second partial derivative to be equal to $0$ in $\theta$, thus for it to have that form.

Something is garbled here: are you really wanting to assert that $u(r,\theta)=f(\theta)$ for all $0\le r\le 1$? There's no reason to think that'd be so... Could you please clarify?

I am using Stein's Fourier Analysis to learn the theory, and in one chapter it said if $u$ tends to $f$ uniformly then they are the same on the entire domain

Ah, ok, but the unit circle is not an open set in the plane, and $f$ itself is not necessarily harmonic, anyway, since the boundary values can be nearly anything. For example, just take $u(x,y)=x=r\cos\theta$, which has $f(\theta)=\cos \theta$. Yes, these are equal when $r=1$, but not otherwise.
